# Spring Boot 2.0 OAuth2 throws 401 Unauthorized

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I created an OAuth2 server using Spring Boot 2.0.  I'm using Bcrypt to encrypt all the passwords, including the client and the user; but I'm still getting 401 Unauthorized error.  The source code is located at https://github.com/saurin-tech/demo-jwt

To test this I'm using Postman.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you want your "/getAllUsers" endpoint to be public, then in your ResourceServerConfig.configure method, you should include:

```
 http.anonymous().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/users/**").authenticated()
                .antMatchers("/getallusers").permitAll()
.and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(new OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler());
```

Comment: I'm aware of that. But, what I'm trying to do is to get a 200 response back when I try to get authenticated with the server.  But the authentication is failing.